# How to set TTL on Hazelcast cache map with spring cacheble

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache

I am using Hazelcast cluster cache with spring boot. I am using the 4.2 version of hazelcast.

Caching is working fine but it doesn't evict the data from the cache map after TTL. Always keeping the same data. I tried a lot of ways of setting ttl but didn't get any success.

Here is my chance config class

```
import com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient;
import com.hazelcast.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance;
import com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

  @Value("${hazelcast.cluster-name}")
  private String hzClusterName;

  @Value("${hazelcast.address}")
  private String hzAddress;

  @Bean
  HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig());
  }

  @Bean
  public ClientConfig clientConfig() {
    ClientConfig cfg = ClientConfig.load();
    cfg.setClusterName(hzClusterName);
    cfg.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(hzAddress);
    return cfg;
  }

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance());
  }
}
```

The cache class where I am using cacheable

```
@Cacheable("items")
public String getInfo(String systemSkuRef) {
  logger.debug("Not using cache, fetch and put in cache");
  return "Item Info";
}
```

I tried by using hazelcast.yaml file in src/main/resources by setting

```
hazelcast:
  network:
      public-address: 
  cluster-name: dev
  map:
    items:
      time-to-live-seconds: 120
      max-idle-seconds: 60
      eviction:
        eviction-policy: LRU
        max-size-policy: PER_NODE
        size: 1000
```

is there any other way or how can I achieve this, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two topologies in which you can use Hazelcast: Embedded and Client-Server. Your Java Spring configuration configures Hazelcast Client, however your `hazelcast.yaml` is dedicated for the Embedded mode.

Try to either use your `hazelcast.yaml` configuration in your Hazelcast server. Or configure your cache in the Hazelcast client, for example, like this:

```
@Bean
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    HazelcastInstance instance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig());
    instance.getConfig().addMapConfig(new MapConfig("items").setTimeToLiveSeconds(120));
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rafal It is working like charm. thank you so much for your help